# Using XQuery in SQL Server 2008 to search for content

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

Take the following 4 example XML documents:

1. <Example>
   <Colour>orange</Colour>
   </Example>
2. <Example> <Car
       colour="orange">Ford
       Focus</Car> </Example>
3. <Example> <County>Orange
           County</County>
           </Example>
4. <Example> <Orange>555</Orange>
           </Example>

These are all stored in a SQL Server database in a table with a XML datatype column (untyped).

How would I go about running a query looking for all content in the document with the word orange in it, which would return the following documents:

1. this has a value orange inside an element.
2. this has a value orange inside an attribute.
3. this has a value Orange County inside an element (note different casing of the word Orange)

Document 4 should not be returned in the query results as the word orange is an element name and is not a data value.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in a single query - however, with two, you should get the results you're looking for:

1. first query to get all XML nodes that contain a text (inside the element) that looks like "orange":

   ```
   SELECT * FROM dbo.XQueryTest
   WHERE XmlContent.value('(//*/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE '%orange%'
   ```
2. second query to do the same, but based on an attribute value:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM dbo.XQueryTest
   WHERE XmlContent.value('(//*/@*)[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE '%orange%'
   ```

Query 1 just grabs the value of the `text()` for all XML nodes as a string (`varchar(50)`) and compares that based on regular SQL syntax against '%orange%'.

Query no. 2 grab all the attribute values (`/@*`) and does the same.

Of course, you can `UNION` those two together, if you really need to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Thanks that works-however it only works if there is one node in the child node, how would I search nodes and attribute values if the Example root node contains multiple child nodes:

<Example>
   <Car colour="orange">Ford Focus</Car>
   <Orange>555</Orange>
   <Colour>Orange</Colour>
   <County>Orange County</County>
</Example>

Comment: ok, after adding that request after about 2 hours of searching for the answer I then went back to more Googling for an answer to this I found it:

SELECT * FROM dbo.XQueryTest
WHERE XmlContent.exist('//*/text()[contains(., "Orange")]')=1